# updateURL: false, does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having a problem with my single page website, since I don't want the url of each section to show up. Unfortunately, the command doesn't work, but the others, like offset, speed or easing, working well. How come? 
Here is my javascript code. Hope someone could help. 
Thank you

```js
$ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul#menu-main-menu-left li a').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('data-scroll','');
  });

  $('ul#menu-main-menu-right li a').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('data-scroll','');
  });

 smoothScroll.init({
 speed: 800,
 easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
 offset: 33,
    updateURL: false,
 pagination: true, 
 responsiveFallback: false,
 loop: false
});

  var nav = $('.navbar-fixed-top');
  var distance = $('.navbar-fixed-top').offset();

  if (distance.top >= 20 ) {
    nav.addClass('effect');
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= 20) {
    nav.addClass('effect');
   } else {
    nav.removeClass('effect');
   }

  });


  // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
        
            function init() {
                // Basic options for a simple Google Map
                // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
                var mapOptions = {
                    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                    zoom: 11,

                    // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.248849, 114.167529), // Hong Kong

                    // How you would like to style the map. 
                    // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                    styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]}]   };

                // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
                // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
                var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat: 22.248849, lng: 114.167529},
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        draggable: true
        });

                // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.248849, 114.167529),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Snazzy!'
                });
            }

});
```